# Spring Batch Java - ejecutar proceso cada X registros

Tags: spring, batch

Estoy desarrollando un Spring Batch que realizará lo siguiente:

1. Reader
   Realizará una select que devolverá varios millones de registros.
2. Processor
   Deberá de ir almacenando los valores que le lleguen y cuando llegue a X registros, realizar una llamada a un SH para ejecutar un proceso externo.
   Estos registros los iré guardando en una Hash para tenerlos disponibles cuando los necesite
3. Writer
   Solo se deberá de ejecutar cada X registros tratados, es decir, en el procesor habrá una especie de contador que vaya skipando el Writer hasta llegar a los X registros

Mi pregunta es la siguiente:

¿Cómo puedo skipar el Writer en cada iteración del Spring Batch hasta que a los X registros lo necesite ejecutar?

¿O hay una forma más fácil de trabajar con bloques sin necesidad de hash ni skippers?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué quiere decir *skipar*? ¿Saltar (del inglés to skip)?

Comment: En este caso tendrías que leer sobre el método `chunk` para poder decirle cuantos items quieres ejecutar y el step que vas a ejecutar.